# Start Django App When Windows Starts

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, tasks, django

I would like to start a Django App automatically when Windows starts.

I created a .bat file (that I intend to execute using Task Scheduler) containing the following:

```
C:\Users\HP\project-name\Scripts\activate.bat
python manage.py C:\Users\HP\project-name\project-name\manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But this doesn't seem to be working... Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the batch script in the Autostart Folder of Windows `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. You can also access this folder by pressing `WINDOWS + R` and typing `shell:startup`. This will run your script at logon of the user.